# cannot use fdb with python windows 10

Tags: python, fdb

I'm unale to connect python to a firebird database using fdb

i successefully installed fdb via pip

my code looks like:

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:C:\\path\\to\\database.FDB',user='SYSDBA',password='123')
```

When i run it, i got the following error:

> File "main.py", line 3, in
>
> con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:C:\tg2\GCVIDE.FDB',user='SYSDBA',password='masterkey')
>
> File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 800, in connect
>
> load_api(fb_library_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 231, in load_api
>
> setattr(sys.modules[**name**], 'api', ibase.fbclient_API(fb_library_name))
>
> File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fdb\ibase.py", line 1396, in **init**
>
> fb_library = WinDLL(fb_library_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 348, in **init**
>
> self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>
> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide

(Translate: "n’est pas une application Win32 valide" => is not a Win32 valid application

Comment: you're most likely trying to load a 32 bit DLL on 64 bit python, or vice versa. The DLL is being loaded by the library.

Comment: So, how to deal?

Comment: well, you just make sure the versions don't mismatch...that's all. If you're on 32 bit python right now, try 64 bit or vice versa

Comment: Thanks you @Chase, i had a 64nits python installation, i removed it and installed a 32 bit (86). and it works.